# Can't install packages with pip (problem with metadata)

Tags: python, pip, metadata

I'm trying to install the pygame module using pip, but it keeps displaying warnings about the package/wheel metadata not matching with the filename (but they do match)

```
$ pip install pygame
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (21.9 MB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/56/0f26c8f73306f68dcc6577d58af04e3014b756aaf2effb9e73e7930707c5/pygame-2.1.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl#sha256=754c2906f2ef47173a14493e1de116b2a56a2c8e1764f1202ba844d080248a5b (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Requested pygame from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/56/0f26c8f73306f68dcc6577d58af04e3014b756aaf2effb9e73e7930707c5/pygame-2.1.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl#sha256=754c2906f2ef47173a14493e1de116b2a56a2c8e1764f1202ba844d080248a5b has inconsistent version: filename has '2.1.2', but metadata has '2.1.2'
  Using cached pygame-2.1.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (21.2 MB)
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/b2/68e2b70d52453dc42a4ad8197cebefd3a26555f9280de6a692cfdeb7d284/pygame-2.1.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=7889dce887ec83c9a0bef8d9eb3669d8863fdaf37c45bacec707d8ad90b24a38 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pygame/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Requested pygame from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/59/b2/68e2b70d52453dc42a4ad8197cebefd3a26555f9280de6a692cfdeb7d284/pygame-2.1.2-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl#sha256=7889dce887ec83c9a0bef8d9eb3669d8863fdaf37c45bacec707d8ad90b24a38 has inconsistent version: filename has '2.1.2', but metadata has '2.1.2'
Downloading pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
       |█▌                              | 471 kB 269 kB/s eta 0:00:36^C
ERROR: Operation cancelled by user
```

Using Python 3.10.5 with pip 21.0

Comment: `pip --version` ? Upgrade? Downgrade? Works for me with `pip` 22.1.2.

Comment: pip 21.0 can't upgrade to newer version same thing happens

Comment: same with python3 -m pip ?

Comment: yes but it also give an another error

Comment: Here is log from python3 -m pip https://pastebin.com/Rj4v1srr

Comment: I see, `Error: Operation cancelled by user`. Ignore warnings, they are just because you've tried it several times, and now it is using a cached version. Don't cancel the installation just because of the warnings and share the output

Comment: Here is a full log https://pastebin.com/B0YrdrH7 it still fails without interrupting it

Comment: The real error seems to be "/bin/sh: line 1: sdl-config: command not found". Install necessary Linux packages: https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileUbuntu